# Yodlee addSiteAccount1 failing to register accounts with "Exception Occurred" message

Tags: node.js, yodlee

I have been trying to get the addSiteAccount1 API endpoint to accept the data I am sending it.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/addSiteAccount1) I have set out the structure below.

The first structure I tried used an array for the current credentialsField object, but I couldn't set "enclosedType" of the credentialFields array... so that was scrapped in favour of an object with numbered keys.

```
{
"cobSessionToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"userSessionToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"siteId": 4252,
"credentialFields": {
  "0": {
    "displayName": "Customer Number(DOB (ddmmyy) followed by unique number)",
    "fieldType": {
      "typeName": "IF_LOGIN"
    },
    "name": "LOGIN",
    "valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD",
    "isEditable": true,
    "valueIdentifier": "LOGIN",
    "value": "123456789"
  },
  "1": {
    "displayName": "Security Number",
    "fieldType": {
      "typeName": "IF_PASSWORD"
    },
    "name": "PASSWORD",
    "valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD",
    "isEditable": true,
    "valueIdentifier": "PASSWORD",
    "value": "123456789"
  },
  "2": {
    "displayName": "Password",
    "fieldType": {
      "typeName": "IF_PASSWORD"
    },
    "name": "PASSWORD1",
    "valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD",
    "isEditable": true,
    "valueIdentifier": "PASSWORD1",
    "value": "password123"
  },
  "enclosedType": "com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle"
}
}
```

Unfortunately, I only ever get the following response from Yodlee, which hasn't helped very much. If anyone can see where I'm going wrong it would be much appreciated.

```
{
"errorOccurred": "true",
"exceptionType": "Exception Occurred",
"referenceCode": "_f2d54a4c-f328-418e-b9fd-cec0be18f5e1"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing the same problem as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744429/yodlee-rest-api-error-adding-new-user-exception-occurred) , please see the answer and follow it.