# Yodlee REST API - error adding new user "Exception Occurred"

Tags: javascript, rest, yodlee

I am trying to use the Yodlee REST API to access our Private Zone and add a new user.  I am using the register3 api which I'm calling at

https://sdkint11.yodlee.com/yodsoap/srest/private-XXX/v1.0/jsonsdk/UserRegistration/register3

The dummy user credentials are as follows:

```
{ cobSessionToken: '10072014_0:58f1876ccc25848a712fade98d9d31c067cb5b4d322094845b4f8359ee59dc2ba01f1e94cfc9d5bd116d32ff6333f84fd848817b9b20cd9b1e85d50774a0ea32',
  userCredentials: 
   { loginName: 'AAAAAA',
     password: 'BBBBBB',
     objectInstanceType: 'com.yodlee.ext.login.PasswordCredentials' },
  userProfile: { emailAddress: 'ABC@DEF.co.uk' } }
```

I've changed the credentials a bit for privacy, and for now I'm only using the 5 mandatory arguments required to establish a new user.

The (not very helpful) error I'm getting is

> {"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"Exception
>   Occurred","referenceCode":"_e37c33ab-b59c-4fbc-ab6a-1a2b83f5784f"}

which doesn't help debugging much.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the parameters in form of objects which will not be accepted by Yodlee. You will have to strictly follow the way it's represented in the [document](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/register3).

So your request parameter should look like for example -

> ```
>  cobSessionToken: '10072014_0:58f1876ccc220950774a0ea32',
>   userCredentials.loginName:'AAAAAA', userCredentials.password:'BBBBBB'
> ```

Please try out the suggested changes.

Comment: Hi, I'm using PostMan for testing the API and I am able to perform coblogin authentication. However, when I try to register a user calling the suburl `jsonsdk/UserRegistration/register3` and setting the parameters specified in the documentation in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format, I get the following error: `{
  "errorOccurred": "true",
  "exceptionType": "Exception Occurred",
  "referenceCode": "_1eed175d-4d05-4644-9a84-913976e9799b"
}`, which is not very informative. Why could this be happening?